# How does ORCID work?

Tags: publications, digital-researcher-id

Will the ORCID appear in the article people write? I could not find an article in which ORCID was included. Can somebody point out some examples if there are any?

Comment: I don't remember seeing ORCID ID in research papers, but I have seen it in several CVs. Perhaps, the reason is that journals' style guides do not allow or support that. In regard to ORCID ID's use, you can use just a numeric form or generate a QR code for CV, papers, poster labels, website and other "marketing" purposes.

Comment: If it does not appear in the article, then how the article written by the person is linked to this ID?
If it would appear in the article then by searching it people could have easily find the profile of the author.

Comment: Papers, authored and co-authored by a person, are supposed to be listed (currently, AFAIK, manually) in the relevant section(s) of the person's ORCID profile, which **uniquely identifies** researcher via the corresponding ORCID ID. That one-way linkage, while not ideal, is, at least, better than no linkage at all.

Comment: I've recently seen journals starting to put the ORCID in the actual papers. Here's an example [pdf](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/19942060.2015.1004788#aHR0cDovL3d3dy50YW5kZm9ubGluZS5jb20vZG9pL3BkZi8xMC4xMDgwLzE5OTQyMDYwLjIwMTUuMTAwNDc4OEBAQDA=).

Comment: "ORCID ID" is one more item in the list that contains "AC current", "ICBM missile," "ATM machine", and "PIN number".

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh. How doe this uniquely identifies the author? If I put another person's article in my profile, who has the same name as I have, then how can the ORCID know I am cheating? ORCID ID must be in the article itself or linked to the article to make this identification possible. Maybe, when I add an article, ORCID asks the publisher for the ORCID ID authors sent during papaer submission and then compare that with the ORCID ID of the person trying to put the article in the profile.

Comment: @yashar Requiring ORCIDs in the source paper would make it impossible to build a complete record for anyone who began publishing before this was standard. Yes, this means you can indeed cheat by claiming other people's papers - the system is not intended to guard against abusive behaviour.

Comment: @Andrew What would it be the benefit of ORCID then?

Comment: @AndreasBlass from orcid.org: "you may only register for an ORCID iD for yourself". So, writing "ORCID iD" is correct. "ORCID" should be pronounced like "orchid", the flower, so it's not too redundant phonetically speaking.

Comment: @pintoch I was aware that ORCID itself does what I'm complaining about, but I decided to complain anyway.  "PIN number" isn't too redundant *phonetically* either, but I complain about that too.

Comment: @AndreasBlass OK, but still it there are differences between the organization running ORCID ("ORCID"), a profile on that system ("ORCID record"), and its identifier ("ORCID iD").

Comment: @yashar The benefit is what it always was - identification. It's not intended to be an absolute legal guarantee of identity, just a way to easily distinguish two people with similar names.

Answer (score 15):

ORCID identifiers do not mean much when you write them on the first page of a paper. Humans usually prefer to see affiliations or email addresses, because they carry more meaning.

However, ORCID iDs are very useful when they are included in the metadata associated with the article. This helps search engines and research information systems identify the authors the paper. As this metadata is rarely shown directly to users, it is not so easy to observe ORCID iDs in the wild. Here are a few examples:

- Some papers registered on CrossRef or DataCite have ORCID iDs associated with their authors. For instance, you can [search for the papers associated with 0000-0001-5556-6616](http://search.crossref.org/?q=0000-0001-5556-6616).
- Some repositories also store ORCID iDs, such as [Zenodo](http://zenodo.org): for instance, [this paper](https://zenodo.org/record/32681) has an id in [its metadata](https://zenodo.org/record/32681/export/dcite3).
- Some research information systems such as [Dissemin](http://public.dissem.in/) display ORCID identified authors with the ORCID logo, as in [this example](http://public.dissem.in/0000-0002-6293-3231/).

Answer (score 9):

[Europe PMC have been displaying it on the site since 2013](http://blog.europepmc.org/2013/11/orcids-in-europe-pmc.html).  Nature also started in 2013 - [click on Chen Dong's name in this article and you'll see his ORCID ID](http://www.nature.com/ni/journal/v14/n7/full/ni.2633.html#contrib-auth).  There are plenty of other examples out there, [Springer](https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/journal-author/frequently-asked-questions/3832), [Wiley](http://exchanges.wiley.com/authors/orcid) etc etc.

ORCID adoption by journals is increasing day by day.  Most major journals now accept it upon submission. [Many of the big publishers are on the board](https://orcid.org/about/team).   Many funders ask for it.  [Wellcome mandates it.](http://blog.wellcome.ac.uk/2015/06/30/who-are-you-recognising-researchers-with-orcid-identifiers/)

Some publishers display ORCID IDs on their article pages or author pages, others have not yet got round to it.  Even if they are not yet displaying it on their article pages, the ID is often propagated to Crossref or Datacite via DOI metadata.  This helps discoverability and disambiguation and also allows for [auto updating of ORCID records](https://orcid.org/blog/2015/10/25/auto-update-has-arrived-orcid-records-move-next-level).